# Ballerina java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while running module/project

Tags: wso2, interop, ballerina, ballerina-java-interop

I am trying Ballerina and Java Interoperability by importing a jar consisting of Java classes code into ballerina and trying to call constructor and methods in the java class through .bal file.

This works perfectly fine when I run .bal file.

```
ballerina run <balfile>
```

However when I run the whole project module it gives me below exception.

```
enter code here
```

```
error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError message=com/example/wrapperpackage/Wrapper cause=error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException message=com.example.wrapperpackage.Wrapper
        at cceackh.implementation:wrapperconstructor(java-test.bal:14)
           cceackh.implementation:main(java-test.bal:42)
PS C:\Users\cceackh\java_ballerina_interop\ballerina_interop>
```

I have saved the jar file in BallerinaHome/distributions/bre/lib folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have already read the guide [How to Structure Ballerina Code](https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-structure-ballerina-code/). When you compile a Ballerina program with `ballerina build <root-module>`, the compiler creates an executable jar file. In this case, the Ballerina compiler produces a self-contained jar file.

If you are using Java interoperability in Ballerina, you need to specify all your jar files in `Ballerina.toml` file so that the compiler can package them within the executable jar file.

Here is how you can specify a jar file dependency in `Ballerina.toml`.

```
[platform] 
target = "java8" 

[[platform.libraries]] 
# Absolute or relative path to the jar file
path = "<path-to-jar-file-1>" 
# A comma-separated list of Ballerina module names that depends on this jar
modules = ["<ballerina-module-1>"]

[[platform.libraries]] 
path = "<path-to-jar-file-2>" 
modules = ["<ballerina-module-1>","<ballerina-module-2>"]
```

```
[platform] 
target = "java8" 

[[platform.libraries]] 
    path = "./javalibs/mysql-connector-java-<version>.jar" 
    modules = ["ordermgt"]
```